# onBeforeUnload event to prevent the "Are you sure you want to leave this page" message appear

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, onbeforeunload

As the title mention, I am trying to prevent the pop-up message "Are you sure you want to leave this page" to appear when clicking a LinkButton in the Modal. 
I've tried to set the onBeforeUnload event on ascx or/and aspx page (I already tried on Javascript and C#). However, the message still pop-up.

Some addition information: The linkButton is calling a postback function which refresh the page. I had tried on setting some event handle on modal toggle/hide. It just doesn't work.

Anyone come up with any idea on how to prevent the message pop?

Some code I tried:

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){ return null; }
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() { return null; });
```

Comment: Maybe try to se the onbeforeunload to null? `window.onbeforeunload = null;`

Comment: But in case the "window" seems pointing the page but not the modal. And I tried to convert to point to the modal but seems not working also.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, finally found out the reason. 
I just missed some of the old code which already defined the onbeforeunload. Therefore, it also pops-up and the code are not covering it.
Just some careless mistake :P
Learnt to read the old code and trace back more on what had done before.